# Prepare a video for low-performance hardware

Tags: performance, html5-video, avconv

I'm trying to play some videos (webm mostly) on some very-low performance hardware. The hardware can barely handle FullHD output.

Since the devices in question are online via 3G modem only, there is some weight on the video size as well. However right now, the playing performance is definitely the more important part.

So, here's the question: Are there any options for `avconv` to improve playback performance? Or should I simply use another codec instead?

Right now, the command used is something like the following:

```
avconv \
    -i $input_file \
    -y \
    -vf scale=$scale \
    -an \
    $output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use ffmpeg instead of avconv (ffmpeg is more active and reliable - my opinion):

- Compile ffmpeg with libvpx support (WebM): [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)
- I would suggest you use [CBR encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8)
- Set --profile to 3: [guide](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/encoder-parameters/), read about some more options if you want
- Generally you would want to lower frame resolution and frame per second as much as acceptable for your project requirement and throw the appropriate bitrate for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach that you can try, that is to shrink the video twice in hight while leaving the width alone:

```
$ avconv -i 01.webm -vf 'scale=w=iw:h=ih/2' -c:v libtheora -c:a copy 01.ogv
```

for me has produced a file 84% the size of

```
$ avconv -i 01.webm -c:v libtheora -c:a copy 01.ogv
```

This way is much better than scalink in width, because it does not damage the text that may appear on the screen quite as much (human brain can for whatever reason deal with vertical distortion easier than with horizontal one).

You can also apply the denoise filter `hqdn3d`, which will make the filesize smaller, but will not damage the quality of the video.

The load on the processor of the playing machine can sometimes be more difficult to predict when one goes from video to video; but there is a difference in codecs. I've not compared them much, so can't offer real assistance.